# Is there a way to find all constant pointers in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, pointer

I would like to know all the constants used for memory access except for non-pointer constants (e.g. argument) in IDA Pro.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Sark's lines](https://sark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/Lines.html) for brevity, this should return all the **cross-referenced** data addresses (with duplicates):

```py
import idautils, sark

for line in sark.lines():
    for ref in idautils.DataRefsFrom(line.ea):
        print(hex(ref))
```

This includes imports and their jump functions from `.text` section as those apparently are marked as data too.

Comment: In my case, I need to find access to physical memory address. In this case, isn't it possible to find all of them with just Xref?

Comment: You cannot get a physical address with static analysis, you need to debug it. Physical addresses depend on the process, they are not static values

Comment: I'm analyzing the firmware. This includes *(int*)0x32000000 = 0x12345678; It contains code like this. I want to get a constant like this.

Comment: If your firmware uses static address translation, all you need to find is the base physical offset, you can calculate everything else